# Observe changes in an input text

Tags: javascript, html

I have a datepicker

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <label for="date">Date</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="birthdate">
 </div>
```

and i have an input text where age is automatically computed based on the selected date on datepicker

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="age">Age</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="age">
</div>
```

this is my function to compute the age

```
getAge: function() {
    let birthdate = oValidationManager.sDate.value;
    if (birthdate != '') {
        let age = moment().diff(birthdate,'years');
        oValidationManager.iAge.innerHTML = age;
    }
    return;
},
```

how can I show the age on age input text after the user pick a birthdate? I tried using event listener such as oninput but it does not work.

Im using [pikaday datepicker](https://github.com/Pikaday/Pikaday)

Comment: you can use jquery change event

Comment: What datepicker are you using? That will decide how you go about approaching this, as default events (such as `onchange`) may not work the same across datepickers.

Comment: updated question. @DevsiOdedra how can I do it on native javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Pikaday, you can use the `onSelect` property to define a function which gets called whenever the selected date changes. For example:

```js
let picker = new Pikaday({
  field: document.getElementById("birthdate"),
  onSelect: (date) => {
    document.getElementById("age").value = new Date((new Date() - date)).getUTCFullYear() - 1970;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pikaday/pikaday.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pikaday/css/pikaday.css">


 <div class="form-group">
     <label for="date">Date</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="birthdate">
 </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="age">Age</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="age">
</div>
```

Comment: is this line computes for the age? new Date((new Date() - date)).getUTCFullYear() - 1970; because i am curious if it is accurate

Comment: @Beginner Yeah, that computes the age (and it will work fine) but I see in your question you are using moment.js, so you should use that instead because it'll do what you want more easily. I just wanted to give an answer with as few dependencies as possible so it was easier to focus on the content.